# Java : Subclassing AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to subclass the android.os.AsyncTask class generically. I basically just want to add a property to it. The thing is, I still want to be able to use it as an anonymous class.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    public class KAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
        public Context c;

    }
```

I have tried subclassing it, but I just can't wrap it around my head how I am supposed to do this.

Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: you might wanna look at this example http://www.etosis.com/posts/asynctask-helpers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You mean you still want it to be an abstract template class like AsyncTask? The declaration would be:

```
public abstract class KAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
    public Context c;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Reuben, that worked. I'll accept your answer tomorrow... I want to share what I did below.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Reuben, it works 100% as expected.

Here is what I have now:

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    public abstract class KAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
        public Context context;

        public KAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> setContext(Context c){
            this.context = c;
            return this;
        }
    }
```

And this is how I use it:

```
    new KAsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connecting to Server...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Responce Recieved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Do webservice calls in here

            return null;
        }

    }.setContext(this).execute();
```

I needed the context to display messages to the user from the task itself.

Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: You could have also used YourActivityName.this from your anonymous AsynkTask, without subclassing.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a way to instantiate an **anonymous inner `AsyncTask`** which also has an instance variable. How do you plan to pass that additional value to the `AsyncTask`?

AFAIK, Java does not allow you to override the constructor of an anonymous inner class. So your only hope is to pass in the `Context` as part of the `Params` type (which happens to be a Varargs). This means you have to make the `Params` type as `Context`; or use a `String` and `serialize`/`Parcel` your `Context` as a `String`. I honestly feel this is not worth the effort and is too much of a hack.

Is there a reason you want to use *anonymous* `AsyncTask`? I would just suggest you create a named implementation of `AsyncTask`.